# Is this servlet thread-safe?

Tags: java, servlets, thread-safety

I need to provide some text by means of a servlet call. The text is obtained from multiple complex database reading, so I have created a file to store the "rendered" text as means of a cache. If the file exists and the cache is not old, the user is redirected to the file, which takes very little time. Otherwise, the file is recreated and the user is redirected to the file afterwards too.

Experienced programmers will have noticed that this has an obvious race condition. First solution attempts to synchronize the block that creates the file. However, this still has a race condition.

Second solution synchronises the whole method and instead of redirecting to the file, it prints out the text within the method.

```
protected synchronized void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

// if file doesnt exist, create file
// if cache is old, recreate file
// printout file
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is this thread-safe? I mean, does the servlet sends all data to the client before it unlocks the object?  Or is the object unlocked and then the servlet starts sending the result to the client?
2. Performance is seriously affected. Is there any other way to increase performance, while keeping it thread safe?

**EDIT**

Just to clarify, the servlet creates the file by means of a call to a static method in another class: `Cache.createFile()`. This method is only accessed by the servlet. The collision of the file with any other external app is extremely unlikely if not impossible. `createFile()` always writes to the same file.

Answer (score -1):

The servlet is thread safe.. but the for each request there is new thread allocated to servlet class and in this case you have multiple thread running for multiple instance of servlet. now it depends on how you have written(code) in you method which may led you in race condition.

But you make some singleton like object with creation logic.

Comment: Mmm... well, actually if there are multiple threads running, only one is allowed to run the method at the same time, so I do not see the race condition depending on how the method is coded.

Comment: Make up your mind. Either it is thread safe or there are race conditions. Your answer doesn't make sense.

Answer (score -1):

As Jigar joshi already had given answer of your question. So you can implement singleton pattern here to improve performance. In your case file is a resource so u have to synchronize it not complete method. Ur code shd look like

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

    if file doesnt exist OR cache is old
       synchronized(this){  // if instance method
          if file doesnt exist OR cache is old  // chk again to avoid re-generation of file
              create file 
       }
    }

    read file data OR printout file 
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but your code is broken (see also double conditions) and does not work for multiple reasons

Comment: Yes, I have seen them. But it fails in many cases. One is that while you are printing the file, any other can enter the synchronized block and modify the file AT THE SAME TIME. Double checks are not safe - you cannot "volatile" the file.

Comment: Then there is only one way - synchronize the access of ur cache, but in this case u have to struggle with performance. Otherwise maintain a copy of ur cache for reading purpose. but this doesn't give any guarantee that readers will get updated data every time.

Comment: The cache per se does not guarantee that data is up-to-date. The synchronisation to the cache is what I have actually done already. I am trying to find performance improvements (as long as the servlet unlocks itself after delivering all data, which tbh I am not totally sure of)

Comment: There is no singleton pattern in evidence here.